# How to update UI without any given event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an react application, where I'm rendering some pictures and gifs, that a user can attach to a post.

Right now I have an `onClick` handler on each image, so that either a modal pops op, wit some different options, or the picture gets deleted (if the user holds down the ctrl key):

```
showModalSpeceficHandler = (event, image) =>{
    let index = this.state.images.indexOf(image)
    if(event.ctrlKey){
     this.state.images.splice(index, 1);
 }else{
 this.setState(
     state => ({imageModalData: image}),
     () => this.showModalHandler()
 );
}
```

The problem is that if the first condition is met the view is not updated automatically. And i can't use and arrow function to re-render since I'm using the splice method on the image. Is there anyway to make the component re render, so that it updates the UI?

I'm not sure if I should wrap the code inside the if condition, inside a separate handler or I can use some Arrow Function syntax or a like?

EDIT:

I updated the method, so I set the state dynamically:

```
 if(event.ctrlKey){
      this.setState(
          state => ({images: this.state.images.splice(index, 1)})
      )
```

The issue now is that I want to return the entire array in not just the selected picture.

Comment: Try using set state instead of directly trying to mutate state -> this.state.images.splice(index, 1);

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basic React usage covered by the first page of the official tutorial and documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are not updating the state properly. If you want to make a change to the state, **you MUST use `setState`**, no matter what, otherwise React doesn't know that it has changed and will not update/render with the changes. See the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) for more details.

Since you need to remove an element from the array, you will have to make a temporary/intermediate copy to modify, then reassign it in the `setState` function:

```
let temp = this.state.images.slice(); //makes a shallow copy of the array
temp.splice(index, 1); //remove item
this.setState(prevState => ({ images: temp })); //update state
```

Comment: To put it slightly differently, `setState` is how you tell React that something changed. If you don't use it, it doesn't know.

Comment: when you call slice the first time, you get a copy of the current array, and then set the state to that array, after removing the index?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) allows you to make a shallow copy of an array so that you're not modifying the state directly. [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) then removes the item at the selected index from the copy. Then the state is updated with the modified copy.

Answer (score 2):

As it was said, you can't mutate the state. If you do so, the component will not be rerendered. What you can do in this case is simply use `setState` in both cases and replace `splice` method with `filter`.

inside of the `setState`

`images: state.images.filter(img => img !== image)`